# Magento pass data by a Query string on a redirect

Tags: php, magento, redirect, query-string

We are trying to pass a boolean through a redirect after an action is completed but we cannot figure out how.

The code for the redirect is:
`$this->_redirect('adminhtml/salesapp/index');`

Does anyone know how we can pass data like this?
`$this->_redirect('adminhtml/salesapp/index?success=TRUE');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$this->_redirectUrl()
```

To pass query in url try like this

```
$this->getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'a=2&b=5'))
```

so try like this

```
$this->_redirectUrl($this->getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'a=2&b=5')));
```